# The bast way to track "modified" of a control?

Tags: wpf, routedevent

I have a usercontrol which may contain many different kind of controls (e.g. button, textbox, combobox or checkbox). I need a generic way to track if anything has been changed. In most cases I don't care about the details (ie I don't need to know which textbox has changed). When I saw `EventManager.RegisterClassEvent`, I thought this would be my solution, but soon I realize it's not. This problem is that it's fired too much. For example, if I have a button and a combobox in the same control, the button.click event is also fired when I hit the combobox dropdown.

In WinForms, I had to loop through all controls in the usercontrol and subscribe to appropriate event (e.g. TextBox.TextChanged, or ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged), it's tedious but works. I hope there is a better and easier way to do it in WPF.

Answer (score 2):

Routed events:

```
<UserControl x:Class="..." TextBoxBase.TextChanged="UserControl_TextChanged" 
Selector.SelectionChanged="UserControl_SelectionChanged" 
ToggleButton.Checked="UserControl_Checked" 
ButtonBase.Click="UserControl_Click" />
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer. The problem is that, using your xaml, if I have a combobox in this UserControl, I will also get UserControl_Click event when I just click combobox's dropdown button. How do I prevent this? For a combobox, I just want SelectionChanged event to be fired after I actually changed the selection.

Comment: Remove ButtonBase.Click event. Another way is to check OriginalSource in the handler. For example, you can add names to the buttons and compare the name of source with allowed buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can Put this checking to validate the e.source in the UserControl_Click event to handle this

```
If(e.Source.GetType()==typeof(Button))
{
  // your code
}
```